# How to replace withFilenamePolicy in Apache Beam 2.4?

Tags: apache-beam

I am trying to read from a Kafka source, partition by a timestamp and write to GCS with Apache Beam 2.4. I want to apply a custom `FilenamePolicy` for the output files.

According to what I have found on Stackoverflow and by Googling this was possible in the past by using

```
.apply(TextIO.write()
                    .to("gs://somebucket/")
                    .withFilenamePolicy(new PerWindowFiles(prefix))
                    .withWindowedWrites()
                    .withNumShards(1));
```

The `withFilenamePolicy` option is no longer available. How is it done in Beam 2.4?

I've tried using the `writeDynamic()` functionality from `FileIO` from the example in the [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.4.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/FileIO.html) - but I don't understand why my `TextIO` is not accepted as an input:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`withFilenamePolicy()` was removed in 2.2

You can now write your example using the simpler syntax

```
pipeline.apply(Create.of(...))
  .apply(TextIO.write()
    .to(new PerWindowFiles("gs://somebucket/"))
    .withTempDirectory(
        FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible("gs://somebucket/tmp"))
    .withWindowedWrites()
    .withNumShards(1));
```

N.B. with a custom FileNamePolicy you will also need to explicitly specify `withTempDirectory`.

In your second (screenshot) example, you are using the default `TextIO.sink()` which is a `FileIO.Sink<String>` to sink `Event`s.  You need either instance of `Sink<Event>` (which will also implement any custom file naming) or to wrap your `Event::getPayload` with `Contextful` like this:

```
.apply(FileIO.<String, Event>writeDynamic()
  .by(Event.getEventType)
  .via(Contextful.fn(Event::getPayload))
```

Comment: FileBasedSink.convertToFileResourceIfPossible("gs://somebucket/tmp") returns localfile system instead of google file system. How to get GcsResourceId, any idea?

Comment: I was creating resourceId at the start of code. It has to be inside the TextIO.write() code. Could not get writeDynamic working though